# Draw a ring topology using python

Tags: python, networkx

I need to draw a topology similar to shown in the picture below. But I am not able to arrange the order of the node and also how to stop edges from crossing randomly.

[image]

Comment: There is no picture below

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR2Ud.png

Comment: Please find the picture in this link, sorry for some reason it did not allow me to post picture

Answer (score 2):

You can hardcode the positions like this:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node(0,pos=(20,20))
G.add_node(1,pos=(30,10))
G.add_node(2,pos=(25,0))
G.add_node(3,pos=(15,0))
G.add_node(4,pos=(10,10))
pos=nx.get_node_attributes(G,'pos')

G.add_edge(0, 1)
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(2, 3)
G.add_edge(3, 4)
G.add_edge(4, 0)

nx.draw(G,pos=pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', node_size=1000, node_color = 'black',font_color = 'white')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I was able to implement the same, but the problem is that node position randomly changes sometime clockwise and sometime anti-clockwise. Also, sometime edges are crossing.

Comment: Edited the answer. you can adjust the coordinates and node position will be the same every time.

Comment: Appreciate your help, actually the number of nodes can also vary, so hard coding positions will not be a feasible solution for me.

Comment: The positions are hardcoded in my solution but nothing is stopping you from defining the pos attribute iteratively..So the real question is what resulting shape exactly do you need if the number of nodes is changing?

Comment: shape should be similar to what you have shared, but nodes can be any number lets say 2 to 8.

Comment: @AbhinavWadhwa, can you please update your question with all those additional details that you mentioned throughout? I think Geom provided a nice elegant solution to your original question. Maybe up-vote their answer?